# CSS Border-box issue

Tags: html, css

I was reading about box-sizing property on W3 school and tried to change box-sizing property of the divs with [THIS EXAMPLE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_js_box-sizing).

When I am clicking on try it button its working as expected, Fitting 2 boxes with width 150px each inside 300px width container. but when I am changing box-sizing property of container to border-box those two boxes are not fitting inside container.

Why this is happeing even though the box widths are adding to 300px which is containers width?

Comment: you narrows size of container, so It wont work, firstly try fit container, then the inside boxes

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. If I use your TryIt Example, first I see the boxes below. Then I click the TryIt button, and the boxes get on one line next to each other, so there is enough space. Maybe it's dependent of the browser version?

Comment: I think, he means it works fine until you add `box-sizing: border-box` to `div.container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer container also has 1px border.

If you don't apply `box-sizing: border-box` to the outer container, then its border does not count into 300px. So the inner area is 300px and two inner boxes fit.

When you add `box-sizing: border-box` to the outer container, its width, padding and border together make 300px, so its inner area becomes only 298px (because of the 1px border on each side), so two boxes inside do not fit any more.

Answer (score 1):

**Your question is:** When I am changing box-sizing property of container to border-box those two boxes are not fitting inside container.

**Ans:** When you added the `box-sizing: border-box;` to `container`, the `container's` width becomes `298px` cause in `300px` its added 2px border, `1px` form `left` and `1px` from `right`.

300px=[ 298px + 1px(left border) + 1px(right border) ]

In that case, either you need to increase the `width` of `container` from `300px` to `302px` **OR** You can decrease the width of inner `div's` from `1px` each like

`div.box {
    width: 149px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens due to `border` and `padding`.

First of all you have to set 0 padding to your `div.box`. Also, if you want padding-left and padding-right than you have to subtract it from the width.

It means you have to subtract 20px(10px `padding-left` + 10px `padding-right`) from the `div.box` width. So your width will be 130px.

Now, for border also you have to subtract the border width from `div.box`. Here border is 3px so, subtract 6px(3px for `border-left` + 3px for `border-right`) from the `div.box`.

So, finally your code will look like,

```
div.box {
    border: 3px solid coral;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 124px;
}
```